# My Web service URl is working fine then why WebService call is returning error code : 404 not found

Tags: web-services

I have a web service which is used to read the data from crystal report. but while i am trying to execute it , its showing "404 not found". I have tried to open web service URL in browser and its opening up there, that means my web service URl is ok. So what can be the reason for this error

Comment: How you call your service?

Comment: I am calling my web service using my java class.